# Fill FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with data from more than one node

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a Firebase Database which looks like this:

```
|---groups
|       |---group1
|       |       |---membernames
|       |              |---CSADFLL
|       |                  |---givenname: "userx"
|       |              |---XZHSDFL
|       |                  |---givenname: "usery"
|---users
|       |---userx
|       |      |---pairofshoes: "5"
```

The users are shown in an FirebaseRecyclerAdapter which is working well. 
But the same Recyclerview should display the amount of shoes too. 
I thought of adding in populateViewHolder a ValueChangedListener for every corresponding value but I can't change the value from within the Listener //edit: it is possible to change the value from within.

How can I accomplish this without changing my firebase structure?

EDIT:

I ended up using a onValueChangelistener in every recyclerview holder. Apparently firebase is able to combine these listeners in the background for fast and efficent queries.